# Match char sequence and other char sequences that do not contain char sequence

Tags: javascript, regex

It may be sound like a question that has multiple occurrences already but I wasn't able to find an answer for JavaScript.

Consider the flowing RegEx:

```
/("|,|\n|[^",\n]+)/
```

It matches some chars in a string and any other sequences that do not contain one of the chars.
`asd"asd,asd\n` would match: `asd`, `"`, `asd`, `,`, `asd`, `\n`.

I am looking for something that matches the similar way but using strings.

**To give a more helpful example:**

Match 'or' and '&' and everything that is not 'or' and '&':

`The constructor is good or bad? The man & the lord are good.`

would match:

`The construct`, `or`, `is good`, `or`, `_ bad? The man`, `&`,`the l`, `or`, `d are good.`

or with matches between []:

```
`[The construct][or][ is good ][or][ bad? The man ][&][ the l][or][d are good.]`
```

Think of it like a string containing a set of strings that are separated by a char sequence like("ab"). And then each string represents a set of other strings separated by another sequence("cd").
I want to match in the big string all those character sequences ("ab", "cd") that are separators and all of the others that aren't.

Comment: Can you describe with words the logic of your expected output? What are the rules to follow here?

Comment: I want to match _something_ (a string) **that is not** _something else_ (another string) and also the _something else_.

Comment: You want to match string that doesn't contain a string...?

Comment: ok the problem is here that what is that something else string and original string...how do they differ..is something else string specific or has any other logical difference in it and first type of string and same for other one

Comment: What is different about **something string** and **somethingelse string**.

Comment: like in your 1st example: asd"asd,asd... all alphabets are matched and non alphabets are taken as separate. But same pattern doesn't follow in 2nd example, where **_a_** is matched despite being the alphabet

Comment: In my first example I used non alphabets to enforce the understanding that they are chars. I want to do the same with strings. I added a more _human_ example. Let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: @razvan I don't understand the logic of second example. Where do you exactly split, and why do you add some characters?

Comment: @Oriol I added some more explanation. Do you get it know?

Comment: Why is the `or` in Lord not matched separately? (Trying to understand your rule)

Comment: @zx81 because I have bad eyes without IDE underlining. Fixed!

Comment: Oh good, that's what I assumed in my answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I'm going to assume that you meant to break the string at the `or` in `Lord`. If not, let me know and I will tweak, as the general technique remains the same.

This is an interesting question because as far as I know, js does not have an option to split a string and keep the delimiter, as PHP does.

However there is a simple way to accomplish this.

**First step:** surround every instance of `or` or `&` with an unusual text block that you will later use to split the string. The regex for this is... drumroll... `(or|&)`

The js code is something like `splitReady = str.replace(/(or|&)/mg, "[SPLIT]$1[SPLIT]");`

The output: `The construct[SPLIT]or[SPLIT] is good [SPLIT]or[SPLIT] bad? The man [SPLIT]&[SPLIT] the l[SPLIT]or[SPLIT]d are good.`

**Second step:** split the string at each `[SPLIT]`

`result = splitReady.split(/\[SPLIT\]/m);`

This gives us (spaces may not appear correctly in the site's mark-up):

`The construct`,`or`,`is good`,`or`,`bad? The man`,`&`,`the l`,`or`,`d are good.`

Comment: This would normally do the job. I am looking for doing this in one step though. I don't know if it is possible or not. That's why I'm asking. If it is possible I would very much like to use it since I already have a function wrote that it is called by at the match. If nothing will come up I would consider this example even though I see 2 things wrong with it: 1 - if the SPLIT is already in the string the whole thing goes crazy, 2 - on large strings(my case) performance is affected.

Comment: @razvan Trust me, if you choose something unique like `[S@P@L@I@T]` there is no danger. :) This is a great solution for your task in javascript because js does not support lookbehinds, which I would normally combine with a lookahead to split around `&` and `or`. You can split before the `or` by using a lookahead `(?=or)|(?=&)` but you cannot position yourself after the `or` for the second split. js does not support lookbehind sorry, even the alternative XRegRxp library.

Comment: So there is no way to do it with RegExp in JavaScript?

Comment: @razvan 99% sure. Google `javascript split keep delimiter` and you will see what I mean. You can split before the `or` and `&` in one pass but not after. If someone makes me eat my words and invents something I'll be glad to learn it too. :) If someone comes up with a better answer two weeks from now you can always unaccept my answer and accept theirs.

Comment: It is ok. I will see how to optimize it a bit though.